# How texturing works

Tags: texturing, materials, vertex-paint

So i was wondering how actually texturing works. Cause i've seen some videos when people use materials on different part of the bodies, like hair, skin, eyes... and not texture.

I have a model he has some clothes on. A vest, body suit, gloves,... Should i use a particular material for each of them and set the color of the material i want for those objects, or should i use a general material for everything and texture them with a color i want?

And also, i'm not sure when to use vertex paint, and when to use texture paint.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider taking the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and checking out sections of the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). As written, your question is not within the scope of this site as I understand it, as it is too broad; there is no single good to your question, because it depends too much on specific details of individual situations. Learning how to model different kinds of materials in different situations. Knowing when to use one method, and when to use a different one is a much more challenging part of using Blender.

Answer (score 1):

A material defines basic properties to be applied to the entire surface of an object. A texture is used to add variety to the material.

For example a material defines a simple blue colour for the cube. The same colour is used over the entire surface, with variation due to lighting.

[image: material settings]

Adding a texture can then add some variety to the colour. In this example I use a cloud texture to add some green patches to the cube.

[image: texture settings]

Textures can be used to alter almost any part of the material properties from diffuse and specular to transparency or normals (that provides the appearance of surface detail without the complex geometry). A single image texture can also be used to define the surface colour of the entire model.

The above example uses blender internal but the same applies to cycles, it is just less separated in cycles, with texture nodes being mixed in with simple diffuse nodes.

Where vertex painting assigns a colour to a single vertex that can be used to colour the model around that vertex, texture painting is used to paint onto an image of any resolution you choose, allowing you to specify much more detail to your texture.